# Custom command block in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am a newbie in Helm. I would like to create a custom helm chart for `authzed/spicedb`

values.yaml

```
authzed:
  replicaCount: 1

  app:
    name: authzed
    image:
      repository: authzed/spicedb
      tag: latest
      pullPolicy: Always
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8443
      - containerPort: 50051
    command: ["spicedb", "serve"]
    env:
      SPICEDB_GRPC_NO_TLS: "true"
      SPICEDB_GRPC_PRESHARED_KEY: "abcdefgh"
      SPICEDB_DATASTORE_ENGINE: "postgres"
      SPICEDB_DATASTORE_CONN_URI: "postgresql://postgres:abcs@postgres-container:5432/databasename?sslmode=disable"
```

and the `deployment.yaml` in helm chart template:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.app.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.app.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.app.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.app.name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.app.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.app.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.app.image.pullPolicy }}
        {{- if .Values.app.ports }}
        ports:
          {{- range .Values.app.ports }}
          - containerPort: {{ .containerPort }}
          {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.app.command }}
        command: {{ .Values.app.command }}
        {{- end }}
        # command: ["spicedb", "serve"]
        {{- if .Values.app.env }}
        env:
          {{- range $key, $value := .Values.app.env }}
          - name: {{ $key }}
            value: {{ $value | quote }}
          {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
```

I am facing an issue when hit deploy:
`Error: failed to start container "authzed": Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "spicedb serve": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

As I investigate the command when I run kubectl describe pod:

```
    Command:
      spicedb serve
```

=> It won't work

I add this line `command: ["spicedb", "serve"]` to `deployment.yaml` and then I get the result as expected.

```
    Command:
      spicedb
      serve
```

So why can I not input the same in the `values.yaml`?  
Any suggestions please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

In a [pod spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#entrypoint), the `command:` is always a list of strings.  On the other hand, the Go template expressions `{{ ... }}` always emit plain strings, with some automatic formatting for non-strings that's not necessarily YAML.

The easiest way to preserve the structure is to use the Helm [`toYaml`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) extension function; for example

```yaml
        {{- with .Values.app.command }}
        command:
{{ . | toYaml | indent 10 }}
        {{- end }}
```

Note the indentation here: the `{{` on the line containing `indent` starts at the first column, and then the `indent` number is the number of spaces it needs to be indented.  Here that number is the indentation of the `command:` line, plus two more spaces.

There are a couple of tricks you can use if you want this to be on a single line.  `toJson` instead of `toYaml` will actually work fine (as a design point, all valid JSON is valid YAML) and always formats to a single line.  You can also use whitespace chomping in combination with `nindent` `{{- ... | nindent 10 }}` to force a new line on to the beginning of the string

Answer (score 0):

I use `- range` for this.

```
        {{- if .Values.app.command }}
        command:
          {{- range .Values.app.command }}
          - "{{ . }}"
          {{- end }}
        {{- end }}
```

and it works